# MySQL SELECT buscando valor em outra tabela

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho 2 tabelas:

`paginas` e `paginas_categorias`

Na tabela `paginas` eu tenho uma coluna chamada `id_categoria`, que seria o id correspondente da tabela `paginas_categorias`. Usando esse id, eu queria retornar a coluna `nome` da tabela `paginas_categorias`.

Vou tentar dar outro exemplo: meu objetivo é que nessa query:

```
SELECT id_paginas FROM paginas
```

retorne o valor `nome` da tabela `paginas_categorias`:

```
SELECT nome FROM paginas_categorias WHERE id = (id informado na outra tabela)
```

Vi que isso seria uma subquery, porém não consegui usar os exemplos com a minha realidade.

Comment: Você precisa utilizar um join para mesclar tabelas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazendo a junção você terá a relação de todos os nomes da tabela paginas_categorias que constam da tabela paginas.

```
SELECT paginas_categorias.nome 
FROM paginas INNER JOIN paginas_categorias 
ON (paginas.i_categoria = paginas_categorias.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi, fica mais ou menos assim a sua consulta...

```
SELECT nome FROM paginas_categorias 
INNER JOIN paginas 
ON (paginas_categorias.id = paginas.id_categorias)
```

Answer (score 2):

Com as respostas dei uma pesquisada e entendi como funciona o JOIN entre as tabelas e consegui fazer retornar os valores como eu queria, segue:

```
SELECT paginas.id, paginas.nome_pagina, paginas_categorias.nome AS nome_categoria, paginas.id_pagina_curtir, paginas.youtube FROM paginas INNER JOIN paginas_categorias ON paginas.id_categoria = paginas_categorias.id WHERE paginas.id_facebook = xxx
```