# Como salvar cores no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Tenho um formulário simples, e um `TYPE=color`. Essas cores são passadas em hexadecimais, mas não consigo salvar no banco. Pois dá o seguinte erro:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERRO: sintaxe de entrada é inválida para integer: "#000000"

Já tentei mudar no banco, mas ele não aceita outra entrada. Alguém tem alguma solução?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque não faz a coluna ser VARCHAR?

Comment: já tentei e não consigo.Da erro dizendo que a entrada e invalida.

Comment: Como foi que você tentou alterar o tipo de coluna no banco? É possível sim. Enfim, se quiser também é possível converter a cor para número e gravar como int mesmo. Que linguagem você usa no servidor?

Comment: Olá uso Postgres. Gostaria de saber sim como faço. Por que tento alterar o tipo no banco mesmo e não da

Comment: To usando php, html e um pouco de js

Answer (score 7):

A estrutura da sua base de dados prevê um relacionamento entre duas tabelas: as cores ficam gravadas em uma tabela (se entendi direito, o valor da cor em hexadecimal), enquanto os dados das roupas ficam em outra. A tabela de roupas faz uma referência para a tabela de cores, gravando o código da cor numa coluna que é uma [*chave estrangeira*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_estrangeira).

Nesse caso, ao inserir uma nova roupa no banco, o que entra na tabela de roupas não é o valor da cor, e sim o código da cor conforme consta na outra tabela (na coluna `cd_cor`). Para obter os dados da roupa e sua cor numa única consulta, você usa um `JOIN`, como demonstrado em algumas outras perguntas aqui do site (por exemplo, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41119/como-fazer-uma-consulta-para-retornar-o-valor-de-outra-tabela) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8319/mysql-select-buscando-valor-em-outra-tabela)).

O que estou achando um pouco estranho é que não faz muito sentido usar uma tabela de cores separada se o seu site permite escolher qualquer cor, em vez de oferecer um número limitado de opções. Se você tivesse opções como "azul marinho" ou "branco neve", faz sentido usar a tabela de cores. Mas se você quer gravar o código haxadecimal da cor, e aceita qualquer cor entre as 16+ milhões possíveis nessa notação, valeria mais a pena ter uma coluna tipo texto diretamente na tabela de roupas, e eliminar o relacionamento entre as tabelas.

---

> **Resposta original**, escrita antes de a autora da pergunta postar a estrutura da base de dados

Eu recomendaria alterar o tipo de dado na sua tabela, e gravar como texto. Para fazer isso no Postgres, você usa o [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html). Por exemplo:

```sql
ALTER TABLE minhatabela
ALTER COLUMN nomedacoluna TYPE char(7);
```

Porém, se quiser mesmo gravar o dado como número, o PHP tem a função [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) que faz a conversão com facilidade:

```
$preto = hexdec("#000000");    // 0
$branco = hexdec("#FFFFFF");   // 16777215
$azul = hexdec("#0000FF");     // 255
$verde = hexdec("#00FF00");    // 65280
$vermelho = hexdec("#FF0000"); // 16711680
```

Provavelmente você vai precisar converter de volta para hexadecimal. Tem a função [`dechex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) para isso, mas você vai precisar colocar o `#` e os zeros à esquerda manualmente. Por exemplo, se usar só o `dechex`:

```
$azul = dechex(255); // "FF" e não "#0000FF"
```

Uma das maneiras de se resolver isso:

```
"#" . substr("000000" . dechex(255), -6); // "#0000FF"
```

Comment: O banco aceita apenas base 10 como número?

Comment: Boa pergunta, não sei.

Comment: @IndaiaraRibeiro Passei as informações aqui dos comentários para a resposta, tentando explicar melhor o que acho do problema (se entendi bem a situação).