# Como fazer uma consulta para retornar o valor de outra tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tabela `PRODUTOS`

- id
- nomedoproduto
- categoriadoproduto
- valordoproduto

Tabela `CATEGORIAS`

- id
- nomedacategoria

No meu formulário eu mostro o nome da categoria mas cadastro no banco de dados na tabela `PRODUTOS` o id da mesma que imagino que seja o certo a se fazer.

Eu tenho que mostrar o produto e sua categoria numa view. Então eu faço a consulta e obtenho como categoria o numero `1` na view do produto através da instrução:

```
<?php while($PA = $BuscaProdutosAtivos->fetch()){ ?>

Nome do produto: <?=$PA['prod_nome']?>
Categoria do produto: <?=$PA['prod_categoria']?>
Valor do produto: <?=$PA['prod_valor']?>

<?php } ?>
```

Como buscar na tabela `CATEGORIA` o `nomedacategoria` para inserir na view uma vez que tenho o `ID` da categoria em questão?

Comment: Obtenha o nome da categoria no mesmo SELECT que você obtém os produtos, fazendo um JOIN. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que seria melhor obter todas as informações de uma só vez, na mesma consulta. Você faz isso com um `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    Produtos.id,
    Produtos.nomedoprotudo,
    Produtos.categoriadoproduto,
    Categorias.nomedacategoria
FROM Produtos
    INNER JOIN Categorias
    ON Categorias.id = Produtos.categoriadoproduto
WHERE /* suas condições */
```